# What causes this to happen to mysql table?

Tags: mysql

Works fine if I SELECT each individual column as well as 2 columns.
By the way, loaded this as text file using LOAD DATA INFILE.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you think has happened here. I would expect a command line display to start and end each row with vertical bar and have vertical bars between columns.

Comment: Can you add a few records from your text file and the load statement you used.

Comment: Things like new lines (\n) can cause this kind effect